# Shift table up after rotating

Tags: tables, rotating

I am using `\rotatebox` to rotate a table 90 degrees counter-clockwise on a portrait page. I am able to center the table horizontally, but not vertically. It sits at the bottom of the page below the page number.

I don't think I can use `\sidewaystable` because I don't want to create a new page; I am using `usepackage{endfloat}` to move all of my tables and figures to the end of the document.

I've tried adding `\vspace*{\fill}` within the table, but this does not seem to work. I've also tried adding `[origin=c]` to get `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}`, but no luck.

Any ideas for how to center this table vertically while still using endfloat?

```
\documentclass[11pt,fullpage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
  \rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Title}
      \label{lbl}
      \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
        blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh & blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh & blahhhhhhhhhh &             
        blahhhhhhhhh & blahhhhhhhhh  \\
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \small
        \item Note.
      \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}
  }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The figure is too big (wide) to fit the textheight when rotated, LaTeX warns in the log. If you hide some of the width it does fit on the physical page though:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fullpage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{Title}
      \label{lbl}
      \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\
        blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh & blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh & blahhhhhhhhhh &             
        blahhhhhhhhh & blahhhhhhhhh  \\
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \small
        \item Note.
      \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}\hspace{-4cm}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```